# R Loop for creating a decreasing array

Tags: r, loops, shiny

I'm a R Beginner and would like to create a function, which creates a decreasing array from point x to 0, taking into account a step size z.

The function should start with x=20000 and should decrease in z=2000 steps 10 times till 0.

The reasoning behind I would like to illustrate the payback of a credit.

```
x <- 20000
y <- 10
z <- 2000

array = [20000, 19000, 18000, 17000, 16000, 15000, 14000, 13000, 12000, 11000, 10000, 9000, 8000, 7000, 6000, 5000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000, 0]
```

Comment: What is `array` ?

Answer (score 3):

To create a sequence starting from `x` with step of `z` and length `y` you can use `seq` as :

```
x <- 20000
y <- 10
z <- 2000
seq(x, by = -z, length.out = y)
#[1] 20000 18000 16000 14000 12000 10000  8000  6000  4000  2000
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rep` to subtract the values

```
x - rep(z, y) * (seq_len(y) -1)
#[1] 20000 18000 16000 14000 12000 10000  8000  6000  4000  2000
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option with `cumsum` + `rep`

```
> x + z - cumsum(rep(z, y))
 [1] 20000 18000 16000 14000 12000 10000  8000  6000  4000  2000
```